# Grails .size().toString() in my list not working

Tags: java, grails

Im trying to get how many is in my list and convert it to string. So that i can show in my gsp how many is in the list. However when i call it, it is null. Although, there when i print it in the console it shows it's actual value

```
def menuItem(Integer max, String category) {
   def categoryList, menuItem

   if(category){
       categoryList = MenuItemCategory.findByName(category)
       menuItem = categoryList ? MenuItem.findAllByMenuItemCategory(categoryList) : []  
   }   
   else{
       params.max = Math.max(max ?: MenuItem.count(), 1)
       menuItem = MenuItem.list(params)   
   }

   def count = menuItem.size().toString()

   println count

   [menuItemInstanceList: menuItem, allCount: count]
}
```

using `${allCount}` in my gsp gives me null

Comment: You do not need `toString()`. In fact you do not need `allCount` in the model. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Domain.list(max)` will return a `PagedResultList`, which has `getTotalCount()` which can be used to find the total count.

in above case:

```
${ menuItemInstanceList.size() } //actual count using pagination
${ menuItemInstanceList.totalCount } //total count
```